# Interested to look for career in salesforce but no background

Tags: administration

i am just wondering if can a person like me, with no background about salesforce or any IT coursE will find difficult to find career in salesforce? I am a registered nurse by the way and i am planning to take up any online course about salesforce or buy books related to it. Will that be possible?

Answer (score 14):

depends. I was a preschool teacher and then took a job as a support rep at a company that used Salesforce. While i was there I learned on the job how to code/develop within salesforce and they let me do it between calls, eventually letting me do it part time, and then full time.

After developing with salesforce for over 7 years I found that there are a lot of weird rules and exceptions that you just can't learn except with experience.

So i think it may be possible since before then i didn't even know how to code at all in any language, but you need someone to give you a chance. And I know that most places want someone with at least a few years experience.

With that said, it never hurts to try :-)

Comment: And, get your admin and dev certs, you can shave a few years off the "experience" that companies are looking for.

Comment: haha I have never had any of those.. but yes, i see that some places want to see them. However, they overlook it if you don't have them depending on your track record :-P

Comment: Of course. I'm cert-less with 9 years experience myself. It's just sound advice for those with less than two years and looking to break in.

Answer (score 7):

If you are smart and work at it you can definitely do it.

Take a look at The Salesforce channels on Youtube.  There are presentations made at Dreamforce about careers in Salesforce field.

Here are two:

- [Salesforce.com Professionals are Here to Stay!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCXiV6b3HKc)
- [Force.com Careers 2.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBJ2m1xwB0Q) - This has a good explanation of the types of roles available.

There are a ton of books and tutorials.  I'd start with the [Force.com Fundamentals Book](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals).

You do not need to know how to code unless you plan on being a programmer/developer.  Product manager, business analyst, admin, QA, etc., don't require computer programming.  However, if you want to start as a developer, as your first position, it definitely does help to have experience developing or some sort of computer programming related degree.

1. Having the certifications can help to show that you have knowledge.
2. Look for volunteer opportunities.  I've seen non profits looking for volunteer help. That will give you experience.
3. Build something useful in Salesforce.com and include that on your resume.

Also, there's a shortage of talent, so that bodes well for you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

There are certainly a number of books available; I'm sure there are online courses as well.  If you want to get a feel for Salesforce.com, there's a lot you can do on your own to learn.

First, go to [developer.salesforce.com](http://developer.salesforce.com) and click on the Signup link at the top of the page.  This will let you signup for a Developer Edition Salesforce.com "Org" (see footnote).  It doesn't matter if you want to develop or not - this is a free, personal, 1-user Salesforce org which you can use to learn, and in which you can experiment.  It will include some sample data so you can start playing with the system.  Use the help links, and explore the online help - there's lots of it.  For example, you might start with ["Learn Salesforce Basics"](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/basics.pdf), a nice introduction to the platform.  Good luck!

**footnote:** A single instance of the Salesforce.com platform is called an Organizaition in Salesforce parlance, and is commonly shortened to "org".

Answer (score 6):

Considering the fact that you have no background of IT, I would recommend you to look for career in Salesforce as Consultant/BA.

When a company purchases Salesforce licenses, it needs to configure/customize Salesforce before actually start using it. This 'Onboarding' is a big business. Salesforce being CRM for SMBs, cannot afford to employ Salesforce Expert, most of these companies are dependant on service providers to fulfill their needs. You can start your career in in such service providers. Typically, they need people who can communicate well with clients, understand their needs & document/fulfill them. Being nurse, I guess you must be really good at communication & must be able to communicate with empathy/sympathy.

Considering background, reading on your own might be a bit difficult to start with; I would suggest to join some course after getting confidence you can dig deeper on our own. This is also a place where you can network with people like you looking for career in Salesforce.

This network will help you get your resume at appropriate desk. Moreover some companies do find talent at such course providers.

Certifications can be really helpful to start your career. Because if HR has 20 resumes all with zero experience & want to shortlist only 5; she will rather prefer ones with certification.

Overall, there is big time talent crunch in the industry, odds are on your side.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 3):

Brent Downey recently posted a [great article](http://adminhero.com/5-steps-to-jump-start-your-salesforce-career/) that will help you here. His 5 main points are:

> 1. Create a Free Developer Account
> 2. Know How to Access Help Documentation
> 3. Start with the Basics
> 4. Join a User Group & Network the Hell Out of It
> 5. Get Social

I would also highly suggest getting some certifications. I wrote a [series on the different certifications](http://jessealtman.com/category/salesforce-certification-series/) and how to prepare for them. Coming from a non-technical background, focus on Admin and Consultant certifications. Those would be your best bet on getting started. It won't be too bad for you and they aren't inherently technical. An Admin/Consultant role is much more like a business analyst than a developer. You need to understand the business to determine what works best for them. That is actually the hard part. The configuration of Salesforce is really just a bunch of point and click functionality.

Answer (score 1):

And of course, have look on Salesforce trailhead https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead or Intro to Point & Click App Development - Udacity https://www.udacity.com/course/ud162

Answer (score 0):

I believe all is possible!  Programming is not hard, if you enjoy it.  Salesforce administration is not hard either, if you enjoy technical administration.  The best way to learn is to just dive into it and watch tons of tutorials online.  Best luck to you!